# Ignore C++ unit tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mstest

Is there a simple way to ignore C++ unit tests in Microsoft Unit test Framework?
The only way I could find is to set the test priority.

```
BEGIN_TEST_METHOD_ATTRIBUTE(FooTest)
    TEST_PRIORITY(1)
END_TEST_METHOD_ATTRIBUTE()
TEST_METHOD(FooTest)
{
}
```

Is there a smarter way to achieve this?

In for example Google Test you can specify tests that can be ignore and write a comment why they are ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TEST_IGNORE()` instead of the `TEST_PRIORITY()` in your code snippet.